# What's a better method for triggering a load() event on cached images?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, image-caching

I'm working on a script that waits for content to load in a hidden `div` before activating a thumbnail that points to it.

> ```
> $('#preload img:first-child')
> .bind('load',activateThumb)
> .each(function(){
>     if(this.complete || this.complete===undefined) $(this).load()});
> ```

The `each` part triggers the `load()` event for images in the cache. I had to add it in order to make the page work in some browsers that don't fire `load()` on cached images.

There is also a [plugin here](http://gist.github.com/268257) that does the same thing essentially, by triggering the load event not "manually" but by resetting the `src` attribute.

From a programming standpoint, which is the more graceful solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resetting the `src` attribute to fire the `load` handler seems like a bit of a hack (based on my knowledge). Unless the author of the plugin has some special reason to do that, or knows something we don't, I would stick with your method of manually triggering `load`.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin [event.special.load](http://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/raw/master/ahpi.imgload.js), which is mentioned in the jquery load-event documentation, solves that in a similar way.