# Getting image width and height with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, height, width

I have a very simple code, which annoyingly was working and for the life of me I can not see why it is now failing:

```
function imageSize(img){
  var theImage = new Image();
  theImage.src = img.attr('src');
  var imgwidth = theImage.width;
  var imgheight = theImage.height;

  alert(imgwidth+'-'+imgheight);
}
```

The "img" variable being passed is the img object, obtained from:

```
jQuery('img')
.each(function(){
    var imgsrc = jQuery(this);
    imageSize(imgsrc);
});
```

Comment: Well, what exactly seems to be the problem? Looks alright to me. Also, why are you using the full-blown word 'jQuery'? Compatibility issues? Why don't you just use '$'?

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that if the image isn't fully downloaded when this code runs, then the width and height will be returned as zero, or possibly some other incorrect value.

Comment: Detecting exactly when an image is fully loaded is surprisingly tricky, since the `.load` event won't fire if the image is pulled from cache. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3554185/901048) for solutions to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image may not have loaded yet. So, try (untested):

```
function imageSize(img){
  var theImage = new Image();
  $(theImage).load(function() {
    var imgwidth = this.width;
    var imgheight = this.height;

    alert(imgwidth+'-'+imgheight);
  });
  theImage.src = img.attr('src');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok - the previous answer I gave was invalid when I tested it on jsFiddle - I created this which does what you want though? Do you *need* to have the "new Image()" part? http://jsfiddle.net/R89Qr/3/ - gave the images some hardcoded dimensions...

I changed your code slightly, so that it does this:

```
 function imageSize(img){
  var theImage = new Image(); // ignoring this part when checking the image width/height
  theImage.src = img.attr('src');
  var imgwidth = $(img).width();
  var imgheight = $(img).height();

  alert(imgwidth+'-'+imgheight);
}

$('img').each(function(){
    var imgsrc = jQuery(this);
    imageSize(imgsrc);
});
```

Comment: That would be true if `theImage` was a jQuery object.

Comment: Yes - v.true, I made some alterations and added a fiddle to make it work.

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree. The non-jQuery JavaScript [image object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp) has width and height properties which should have been retrieved in the original code sample -- if the image was fully loaded at the time the code was run.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait , till your image will be loaded , and then access to its sizes:

```
function imageSize(img){
  var theImage = new Image();
  theImage.onload = function(){
    var imgwidth = theImage.width;
    var imgheight = theImage.height;

    alert(imgwidth+'-'+imgheight);
  }
  theImage.src = img.attr('src');

}
```