# jQuery image each loop issue

Tags: jquery

I am currently looping through a set of images to check each image's width. If the image width is less than the image height, I want to add 'Class A' to that particular image, if not I want to add 'Class B' to that particular image.

I can get this to work, but it is quite temperamental. It usually works, but sometimes it adds 'Class B' to an image, when it should be adding 'Class A'. I've tried to also use boolean values to make sure each part of the function fires when it should, but I still get the same result. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Code below:

```
loadContent = function() {
        //set up ajax
        ajaxLoader.ajaxStart(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(200);
        }).ajaxStop(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(200);

        //load the content
        fixedWrap.load(postLink, function() {
            var loopingImages,
                slideImage = $('.ddbSlide img'),
                slideImageFirst = $('.ddbSlide img:first');

                //start the image loop
                slideImage.each(function() {
                var imgWidth = $(this).width(),
                    imgHeight = $(this).height();
                loopingImages = true;
                //
                if (imgWidth <= imgHeight) {
                    $(this).addClass('ddbImagePortrait');
                    $(this).css({ left: '55%' });
                    loopingImages = false;
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('ddbImage');
                    $(this).css({ left: '34%' });
                    loopingImages = false;
                }
            });

            if (loopingImages == false) {
                var checkingClass;
                if (slideImageFirst.hasClass('ddbImagePortrait')) {
                    $('.articleTextWrap').css({ left: '20%' });
                    checkingClass = false;
                } else {
                    $('.articleTextWrap').css({ left: '5%' });
                    checkingClass = false;
                }
                if (checkingClass == false) {
                addSlider();
                }
            }

            return false;
        })
    }; //END loadContent function
```

Comment: The most likely problem is that you're trying to check image dimensions before the image has loaded completely. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787511/getting-image-width-and-height-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check width and height after the image is loaded:

```
slideImage.each(function() {

    $(this).load(function(){
        //image successfully loaded, do stuff here
        console.log($(this).height());
    }).error(function(){
        //something went wrong
    });
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks to everyone for their help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 problems

First `loopingImages` alway `false` so try this for that,

```
loopingImages = true;
//
if (imgWidth <= imgHeight) {
    $(this).addClass('ddbImagePortrait');
    $(this).css({ left: '55%','position':'relative' });
} else {
    $(this).addClass('ddbImage');
    $(this).css({ left: '34%' ,'position':'relative'});
    loopingImages = false;
}
```

Second again `checkingClass` is always `false` for this try,

```
var checkingClass;
if (slideImageFirst.hasClass('ddbImagePortrait')) {
    $('.articleTextWrap').css({ left: '20%','position':'relative' });
    checkingClass = true;
} else {
    $('.articleTextWrap').css({ left: '5%' ,'position':'relative'});
    checkingClass = false;
}
```